# Edit Multiple UIView in 1 XIB

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I got a view written as a set of views ontop of each other all in 1 XIB file... ugly! how do I select a view then bring its controls to the front in Interface Builder? One ways is to remove all the other views ontop of the one that am looking for but that will result in me having difficulties to then add everything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the left sidebar (sorry, I don't know way that view is called, but it's not the project browser) Object menu to elect the view you wish to edit.  You can also use the Edit->Arrange menu to bring views forward or back in the view stack if you wish.